# pywinauto with different languages

Tags: python, pywinauto

For a tutorial with pywinauto, I tried below

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
my_app=Application(backend="uia").start("notepad.exe")
my_app.AdsızNotdefteri.menu_select("Düzen->Değiştir")
my_app.window_(title_re="Değiştir").invoke()
```

But returned error as `ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re': 'Değiştir', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 10292}`
The problem is I am using different language of Windows so How can I get correct titled names of menu items ?

Comment: Which line returned this error? This one `my_app.window_(title_re="Değiştir").invoke()` ? You can try `print([w.window_text() for w in my_app.windows()])` to find correct text.

Comment: `['Adsız - Not Defteri']` printed. How can I get true text str of "Değiştir"  for replacement. I need to run  `my_app.Değiştir.editl.set_text("sometext")` but gave error like same as my_app.window

Comment: Maybe the dialog window is a child of top level window. Then you should start from top level one and add the second level: `my_app['Adsız - Not Defteri'].child_window(title_re="Değiştir").invoke()`

Comment: got `ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'title_re': 'Değiştir', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Adsız - Not Defteri', Notepad, 212143280>, 'backend': 'uia'}`

Comment: Then it can be extended with `found_index=0` or `found_index=1` inside `child_window()` search criteria.

Comment: returned as`NoPatternInterfaceError`. I tried to inspect`**criteria` with `inspect.getargspec(my_app.AdsızNotdefteri.child_window)` but it returned as 'criteria'. How can I get parameters in criteria (e.g: found_index or title_re)

Comment: Why you need to get it? It should look so: `my_app['Adsız - Not Defteri'].child_window(title_re="Değiştir", found_index=0).invoke()`. Maybe one of these 2 found elements doesn't have `InvokePattern`. Screenshot from `Inspect.exe` for the target element would be helpful. Don't forget to switch `Inspect.exe` into "UI Automation mode".

Comment: If the element is found, just get `.wrapper_object()` first, then explore wrapper object methods by `dir()` function or by auto-completion in IDE.

Comment: Tried again and I got `NoPatternInterfaceError`. I want to learn the parameters inside the `**criteria` in `child_window`

Comment: All the keywords can be found in [find_elements(...)](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements) function docs or in source code. `NoPatternInterfaceError` means that element is found. But it doesn't have InvokePattern. Try `.draw_outline()` instead to check it is right element found.

Comment: `.draw_outline()` drawed the window. But still I could not type anything in text box input in chiild window of "Değiştir" as `my_app.değiştir` returns error

Comment: How can I get the correct word of window title to give input in textbox

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but all info was already answered: just replace `my_app.değiştir` to `my_app["değiştir"]` because key access works the same way as attribute access, but it has less restrictions on key name.